# DB table data retrieving error

Tags: magento

I need to retrieve db table data. There is a function in my collection.php

```
public function getfinaltabledata(){
echo $collection = Mage::getModel('exam/excludeid')->getCollection();
var_dump($collection->getData());exit;
$keys = array_keys($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
}
```

But data not loading. Please help...

Comment: Does the data really exists in your custom table ?

Comment: yes there are four records

Comment: How are you calling your function to fetch data ? and what does `$collection` prints ?

Comment: in my .phtml file i called it as $this->getfinaltabledata();

Comment: and am not getting anything as the output

Comment: you need to config.xml code here ,for check the issue

Comment: <models>
          <exam>
                <class>Final_Exam_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>exam_mysql4</resourceModel>
          </exam>
          <exam_mysql4>
                <class>Final_Exam_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>    
                    <excludeid>
                          <table>finaltable</table>
                    </excludeid>
                </entities>
          </exam_mysql4>
        </models>

Comment: when i retrieve data through the controller, i am getting table data. But still couldn't get through the collection.php

Comment: can you pleas Colection.php is exits on check Final>Exam>Model>Mysql4>Excludeid>Collection.php

Comment: yes it is in correct path

Answer (score 0):

What does your config.xml  tag contain? Have you correctly setup your entities/table and resource model?

Comment: yes i did it. <exam_mysql4>
                <class>Final_Exam_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>    
                    <excludeid>
                          <table>finaltable</table>
                    </excludeid>
                </entities>
          </exam_mysql4>

Comment: No that it should matter that much, but why do you use mysql4?

Also (just to verify), your resource model contains this then? 
    $this->_init('<model tag>/excludeid', '<primary_key>');

Although I'm not 100% sure it was also like this when using mysql4 instead of resource

Comment: i just use it, because we are always using that and lso it works on any version

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with code snippets? Would like to see:  
 1. your model and resource model  
 2. your config.xml